# joy of clojure, macros

Tags: macros, clojure, symbols

I have been going through the joy of clojure exercises and came across this example

```
(defn build-contract [c]
    (let [args (first c)]
      (list
       (into '[f] args) ;; here is where i am confused
       (apply merge
              (for [con (rest c)]
                (cond (= (first con) :require)
                      (assoc {} :pre (vec (rest con)))
                      (= (first con) :ensure)
                      (assoc {} :post (vec (rest con)))
                      :else (throw (Exception. (str "Unkown tag " (first con)))))))
       (list* 'f args)))) ;; and here

  (defn collect-bodies [forms]
    (for [form (partition 3 forms)]
      (build-contract form)))

  (defmacro contract [cg & forms]
    (list* `fn cg (collect-bodies forms)))
```

i cant seem to understand why you would want a symbol called f in that vector. symbols are references to things, so what would f reference to? and why do we need to reference it?

Comment: I don't have a copy of Joy of Clojure at hand but I am surprised that they don't use a `(gensym)` instead of the qualified `f`. Given that an `arg` could be referred to as `f` their code could mess up quite badly.

Comment: @lgrapenthin Maybe that's the first step in that lesson?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro builds a function literal expression (an `fn` form).

```
(into '[f] args) ;; here is where i am confused
```

This is the argument vector. The `f` appears here in the role of the formal argument.

```
(list* 'f args)))) ;; and here
```

This is function application. `f` is a function argument and here it's applied to the `args`.

When built, the resulting definition will look something like this.

```
(fn name [f arg1 arg2] ... (f arg1 arg2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Symbols are references to things indeed, that particular macro is building a function, and symbol `f` refers to a function parameter `f` received by that function. (The macro is building a function that receives a function as parameter, named `f`)

Inside the macro, when you need to refer to a named parameter, that's your `f`.

In this particular case this:

```
(into '[f] args)
```

Is the same as:

```
(into ['f] [a1 a2 a3])
```

Which is building the function arguments as in

```
(fn cg [f a1 a2 a3] ...
```

Last call is just function invocation

```
 (f a1 a2 a3)
```